# "wh" command is not showing source code in GDB

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I performed the following steps:

1. gdb executable
2. b foo
3. r
4. wh

Here `wh` should show source code so I can debug from the `foo` method. But source code is not showing.

Comment: A program has to be compiled with [debug symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) for the source code to show. Production builds often omit these to shrink the binary's size.

Comment: What is the command to compile with debug symbols.

Comment: `gcc -g your_program.c`

Comment: You can fine tune the level of information provided in the debugging symbols. The default is level 2, but with level 3 (-g3) you can access macro definitions from within gdb.